# How to extract all levels from a netcdf file using the raster package?

Tags: r, r-raster, netcdf4

Related to this question [Plotting netcdf file with levels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538582/plotting-netcdf-file-with-levels-in-r)

But I would like to know how to extract all levels from a netcdf file automatically, without going through one at a time. Do I have to write a custom function or is there a function in raster package that does that?

Comment: Write your own function. 3Do you have an example netCDF file?

Comment: Use the raster::stack or raster::brick function, it will automatically iterate through the netcdf file and add all of the levels (rasters). The result will be a "stack" or "brick" object containing all of the rasters.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I did that but it extracts only the first level.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer not sure if I can upload it because it might be proprietary.